# Confidence interval as RV

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

Paraphrased question from textbook for my intro to prob. class, and just wanted to verify my intuitions:

> Consider 1000 95% CIs for independently-selected datasets. How many CIs do you expect to contain $\mu$? What is the probability that between 940 and 960 CIs contain $\mu$?

The problem concludes with this hint:

> [Hint: Let Y = the number among
>   the 1,000 intervals that contain $\mu$. What kind of
>   random variable is Y?]

The first part seems straightforward: you would expect 95% of 1000 -> 950 CIs to contain $\mu$.

The second part is where I need someone to cluebat me if my intuition/understanding is incorrect. It's essentially a series of experiments that either succeed or fail, and is therefore a binomial distribution, in this case with n = 100 and p = .95. Am I correct, or, if not, where does it look like I'm going off the rails?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. And a keyword here is "independently-selected". This guarantees that your Bernoulli trials are independent and therefore number of successes indeed follows binomial distribution.

Comment: Good to know I'm not a Dunning-Krueger victim. Thanks for the guidance.